# Obtaining the phone number and phone ID for a phone in android

Tags: android

everyone. I have to build an Android application and one requirement is to be able to record the phone number and the phone ID. Is there any to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be   TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()

Answer (score 0):

Correct code :

```
TelephonyManager telManager;
telManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can get the telephone number, but it's usually inaccurate information (whatever the user has entered manually in the settings, if anything).

This is the code to do it:

```
TelephonyManager tm;
String phoneNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
String IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
```